# Clusters V3 on google maps - javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have moving markers all over the map and i want to refresh clusters depends of markers.
I tried redraw() but it's not ok.

I will appreciate any help help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source, it seems like you can pass a opt_nodraw flag to the addMarker method. Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
/**
 * Add an array of markers to the clusterer.
 *
 * @param {Array.<google.maps.Marker>} markers The markers to add.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_nodraw Whether to redraw the clusters.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.addMarkers = function(markers, opt_nodraw) {
  for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
    this.pushMarkerTo_(marker);
  }
  if (!opt_nodraw) {
    this.redraw();
  }
};
```